# Short "if" in python in case of append into array

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I would like to use an inline if statement to append data to an array if it is not already in the array, as in:

```
arr.append( data if not data in arr )
```

But this code returns:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Is there any other option?

Comment: You need an `else` in there somewhere.

Comment: There is no "short if". Just use an `if` statement if you want to use an `if` statement.

Comment: or reverse it : `if not data in arr: arr.append( data)`

Comment: @PRMoureu that should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
arr.extend([data] if data not in arr else [])
```

#### Examples

Let's start with a sample array:

```
>>> arr = [1, 2, 3]
```

Now let's try `data = 4` which is not in `arr`:

```
>>> data = 4
>>> arr.extend([data] if data not in arr else [])
>>> arr
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now let's try with `data = 2` which is a value already in `arr`:

```
>>> data = 2
>>> arr.extend([data] if data not in arr else [])
>>> arr
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This leaves `arr` unchanged as it should.

#### Notes

1. `append` will append something.  Since it seems that we only want to append if data is not in `arr`, this is not the right method to use.  The method `extend` avoids this problem.
2. `[data] if data not in arr else []` will return `[data]` if `data` is not in `arr`.  Otherwise, it will return `[]`.
3. `arr.extend([])` leaves `arr` unchanged.
4. `arr.extend([data])` adds the element `data` to the end of `arr`.

Comment: wow, thanks for great explanation ! everything works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Inline if statements must contain an else statement too, as in `data if not data in arr else 3`

Note that this example does not work.

Answer (score -1):

```
arr if data in arr else arr.append(data)
```

(This returns `arr` unchanged if `data` already exists in it else appends. (Yes, we are abusing side effects))

```
>>> L = [1,2,3]
>>> a = 4
>>> L if a in L else L.append(a)
>>> L
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> L if a in L else L.append(a)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this? Nice idea, but doesn't look like it will work to me.

Comment: yeah, it doesn't work and returns "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"